# Geospatial support, SQL Server 08 vs MongoDB?

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, sql-server-2008, geospatial, database

MongoDB has lots of street cred especially since FourSquare uses it.  MS SQL Server 2008 R2 also has Geospatial support.

Which DB is easier/better for doing GPS-like search? e.g. k-nearest points around point X,Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Geospatial Queries with MongoDB

http://blog.mxunit.org/2010/11/simple-geospatial-queries-with-mongodb.html

Much easier to use then SQL Server! I like it.

Answer (score 1):

If the only Geospatial function you need is to find *k-nearest points around point X,Y* then any old database will do.  Just use Haversine formula, and it's been [implemented in a bunch of languages](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Calculate_Distance_Between_Two_Points_on_a_Globe).

Comment: With SQL Server 2005 you'd have a regular table of records with fields for the address. You'd add columns for the latitude & longitude and then have a batch process that would take each address as input and fill in the lat/longs. This is called "geocoding" and can be done using a web service like Google/Yahoo/GeocoderUS. Then your app code would take an input lat/long & perform the search of the table using Haversine. You are right to question the performance since this sweeps the entire table, but the algorithm isn't complex (in Big-O terms; there isn't recursion or anything).

Comment: Thanks for the great link to the language implementations for Haversine formula

Answer (score 0):

To make a long story short, SQL Server is way more robust than mongo with geospatial support. However, if you are just storing points on a map and want to calculate distances, mongo is more than adequate.

MongoDB supports Geospatial points. SQL Server supports geospatial objects of an arbitrary number of points.

Either solution will be fine for your geospatial needs, so its more about your data model, scalability, and what database your comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at PostGre. GeoSpatial data processing is where PostGre excels in. Can't really tell you about Windows performance however